# Two GC420t printers different ZPL Outcome (ZPL, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

i have 2 Zebra GC420t printers and a wpf application creating and sending ZPL code to selected printers. 
The printed labels are too way different. See the image below.

[The outcomes and printer configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNYXS.jpg)

Pinted ZPL code is: (label is 10x8.1 cm)

```
^XA

^PON
^CI27
^MMT
^PW800
^LL648

^FX Pictogram0
^FO632,104
^GFA,1300,1300,13,,W0G1GCM0W0G3G4M0,::::::::::::::::::::::::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,:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
^FS

^FX Pictogram1
^FO632,280
^GFA,1300,1300,13,,:::::::::::::::Q0GFGES0P0G7HFGCR0P0IFGER0O0G3JFG8Q0O0G7JFGCQ0::O0KFGEQ0:O0G7JFGCQ0:::::O0G3JFG8Q0::::::O0G1JFR0::::::P0IFGER0:::::P0G7HFGCR0::::::P0G3HFG8R0::P0G1HFS0Q0GFGES0Q0G3G8S0,::Q0G7GCS0P0G1HFS0P0G3HFG8R0P0G7HFGCR0P0IFGER0:O0G1JFR0::::::P0IFGER0P0G7HFGCR0:P0G1HFS0Q0GFGES0,::::::::::::::
^FS

^FX Pictogram2
^FO632,456

^FS

^FX ItemNumber
^CF0,30
^FO25,27,0
^FB608,1,,L,
^FH
^FD
10001A
^FS

^FX ItemName
^CF0,50
^FO25,55,0
^FB608,1,,L,
^FH
^FD
_52_55_43_4F_47_45_4E_20_44_46_4C_20_33_30_30
^FS

^FX BatchNumber
^CF0,50
^FO25,105,0
^FB608,1,,L,
^FH
^FD
17-0001
^FS

^FX Amount
^CF0,30
^FO25,150,0
^FB608,1,,L,
^FH
^FD
120 Kg
^FS

^FX LabelDate
^CF0,30
^FO25,185,0
^FB608,1,,L,
^FH
^FD
29.05.2017
^FS

^FX Barcode
^FO25,230,0
^BY3,2,75
^BCN
^FD
869316388539
^FS

^FX Warnings
^CF0,20
^FO25,350,0
^FB560,30,,,L,
^FH
^FD
_48_33_30_32_3A_20_59_75_74_75_6C_6D_61_73_69_20_68_61_6C_69_6E_64_65_20_7A_61_72_61_72_6C_69_64_69_72_2E_5C_26_48_33_31_38_3A_20_43_69_64_64_69_20_67_F6_7A_20_68_61_73_61_72_69_6E_61_20_79_6F_6C_20_61_E7_61_72_2E_5C_26_50_32_36_34_3A_20_45_6C_6C_65_E7_6C_65_6D_65_64_65_6E_20_73_6F_6E_72_61_20_85_20_69_6C_65_20_69_79_69_63_65_20_79_69_6B_61_79_69_6E_2E_5C_26_50_32_38_30_3A_20_4B_6F_72_75_79_75_63_75_20_65_6C_64_69_76_65_6E_2F_6B_6F_72_75_79_75_63_75_20_6B_69_79_61_66_65_74_2F_67_F6_7A_20_6B_6F_72_75_79_75_63_75_2F_79_FC_7A_20_6B_6F_72_75_79_75_63_75_20_6B_75_6C_6C_61_6E_69_6E_2E_A0_5C_26_50_33_31_30_3A_20_48_65_6D_65_6E_A0_55_4C_55_53_41_4C_20_5A_45_48_49_52_20_44_41_4E_49_53_4D_41_20_4D_45_52_4B_45_5A_49_4E_49_4E_20_31_31_34_20_4E_4F_4C_55_20_54_45_4C_45_46_4F_4E_55_4E_55_A0_76_65_79_61_20_64_6F_6B_74_6F_72_75_2F_68_65_6B_69_6D_69_20_61_72_61_79_69_6E_2E_A0_5C_26_50_33_30_31_2B_50_33_31_32_3A_20_59_55_54_55_4C_44_55_47_55_4E_44_41_3A_20_4B_65_6E_64_69_6E_69_7A_69_20_69_79_69_20_68_69_73_73_65_74_6D_69_79_6F_72_73_61_6E_69_7A_A0_55_4C_55_53_41_4C_20_5A_45_48_49_52_20_44_41_4E_49_53_4D_41_20_4D_45_52_4B_45_5A_49_4E_49_4E_20_31_31_34_20_4E_4F_4C_55_20_54_45_4C_45_46_4F_4E_55_4E_55_A0_76_65_79_61_20_64_6F_6B_74_6F_72_75_2F_68_65_6B_69_6D_69_20_61_72_61_79_69_6E_2E_5C_26_50_33_30_35_2B_50_33_35_31_2B_50_33_33_38_3A_20_47_D6_5A_20_49_4C_45_20_54_45_4D_41_53_49_20_48_41_4C_49_4E_44_45_3A_20_53_75_20_69_6C_65_20_62_69_72_6B_61_E7_20_64_61_6B_69_6B_61_20_64_69_6B_6B_61_74_6C_69_63_65_20_64_75_72_75_6C_61_79_69_6E_2E_20_54_61_6B_69_6C_69_20_76_65_20_79_61_70_6D_61_73_69_20_6B_6F_6C_61_79_73_61_2C_20_6B_6F_6E_74_61_6B_20_6C_65_6E_73_6C_65_72_69_20_E7_69_6B_61_72_74_69_6E_2E_20_44_75_72_75_6C_61_6D_61_79_61_20_64_65_76_61_6D_20_65_64_69_6E_2E_5C_26_50_35_30_31_3A_20_49_E7_65_72_69_67_69_2F_6B_61_62_69_20_85_20_62_65_72_74_61_72_61_66_20_65_64_69_6E_2E
^FS

^FX FormNumber
^CF0,30
^FO600,630,0
^FB160,1,,C,
^FH
^FDF 540.006.2^FS

^XZ
```

You can chech zpl code in labelary.com/viewer.html

I am using [RawPrinterHelper](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322091/how-to-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-visual-c-.net) to send ZPL string to printer.

Can anyone help me please ?

To any poor soul like me that strangling to print an image using ZPL language, here what i have done.

```
    int x = 300, y = 300;
    pictogram0 = ZplImageConverter.GetZpl(ZplTools.ResizeImageData(ZplTools.RotateImageData(pictogramList[0]), x, y));

public class ZplImageConverter
  {
    public const int MaxBlacklimit = 765;
    private static Dictionary<int, String> CompressMap
    {
      get
      {
        if (_CompressMap == null)
        {
          _CompressMap = new Dictionary<int, string>();
          _CompressMap.Add(1, "G");
          _CompressMap.Add(2, "H");
          _CompressMap.Add(3, "I");
          _CompressMap.Add(4, "J");
          _CompressMap.Add(5, "K");
          _CompressMap.Add(6, "L");
          _CompressMap.Add(7, "M");
          _CompressMap.Add(8, "N");
          _CompressMap.Add(9, "O");
          _CompressMap.Add(10, "P");
          _CompressMap.Add(11, "Q");
          _CompressMap.Add(12, "R");
          _CompressMap.Add(13, "S");
          _CompressMap.Add(14, "T");
          _CompressMap.Add(15, "U");
          _CompressMap.Add(16, "V");
          _CompressMap.Add(17, "W");
          _CompressMap.Add(18, "X");
          _CompressMap.Add(19, "Y");
          _CompressMap.Add(20, "g");
          _CompressMap.Add(40, "h");
          _CompressMap.Add(60, "i");
          _CompressMap.Add(80, "j");
          _CompressMap.Add(100, "k");
          _CompressMap.Add(120, "l");
          _CompressMap.Add(140, "m");
          _CompressMap.Add(160, "n");
          _CompressMap.Add(180, "o");
          _CompressMap.Add(200, "p");
          _CompressMap.Add(220, "q");
          _CompressMap.Add(240, "r");
          _CompressMap.Add(260, "s");
          _CompressMap.Add(280, "t");
          _CompressMap.Add(300, "u");
          _CompressMap.Add(320, "v");
          _CompressMap.Add(340, "w");
          _CompressMap.Add(360, "x");
          _CompressMap.Add(380, "y");
          _CompressMap.Add(400, "z");
        }

        return _CompressMap;
      }
    }
    private static Dictionary<int, String> _CompressMap;
    public static string GetZpl(byte[] imageData, bool useCompression = true)
    {
      var imgConverter = new ImageConverter();
      var bmp = (Bitmap)imgConverter.ConvertFrom(imageData);

      var bytesPerRow = bmp.Width / 8;
      if (bmp.Width % 8 > 0)
        bytesPerRow = (((int)(bmp.Width / 8)) + 1);
      else
        bytesPerRow = bmp.Width / 8;
      var totalBytes = bytesPerRow * bmp.Height;

      string hex = CreateMonochromeHex(bmp, bytesPerRow, totalBytes);
      return string.Format("^GFA,{0},{0},{1},{2}", totalBytes, bytesPerRow, useCompression ? EncodeHexAscii(hex, bytesPerRow) : hex);
    }

    #region Helpers
    private static string CreateMonochromeHex(Bitmap bmp, int bytesPerRow, int totalBytes)
    {
      var sb = new StringBuilder();
      var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
      graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
      var auxBinaryChar = new char[] { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' };

      int index = 0;
      for (int h = 0; h < bmp.Height; h++)
      {
        for (int w = 0; w < bmp.Width; w++)
        {
          //Remove borders
          if (h == 0 || w == bmp.Width - 1 || w == 0 || h == bmp.Height - 1)
          {
            auxBinaryChar[index] = '0';
            index++;
          }
          else
          {
            var rgb = bmp.GetPixel(w, h);
            char auxChar = '1';

            /* Determine using Luma
             * Source1 = http://web.archive.org/web/20141017085834/http://nicholas.piasecki.name:80/blog/2013/02/using-the-epl2-gw-command/
             * Source2 = http://web.archive.org/web/20141025194839/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)
             * 
             * var threshold = 127;
             * var color = bitmap.GetPixelx, y;
             * var luminance = color.R * 0.3 + color.G * 0.59 + color.B * 0.11;
             * dotsindex = luminance < threshold;
             * 
             */

            //If color is not pure white then apply thermal heat to draw black otherwise do not apply thermal heat to draw nothing (white)
            if ((rgb.R + rgb.G + rgb.B) >= ZplImageConverter.MaxBlacklimit)
              auxChar = '0';

            auxBinaryChar[index] = auxChar;
            index++;
          }

          if (index == 8 || w == (bmp.Width - 1))
          {
            sb.Append(FourByteBinary(new String(auxBinaryChar)));
            auxBinaryChar = new char[] { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' };
            index = 0;
          }
        }
        sb.Append("\n");
      }
      return sb.ToString();
    }
    private static string FourByteBinary(string binaryStr)
    {
      return string.Format("{0:X2}", Convert.ToByte(binaryStr, 2));
    }
    private static string EncodeHexAscii(string hex, int bytesPerRow)
    {
      int maxlinea = bytesPerRow * 2;
      var sbCode = new StringBuilder();
      var sbLinea = new StringBuilder();
      String previousLine = null;
      int counter = 1;
      char aux = hex[0];
      bool firstChar = false;
      for (int i = 1; i < hex.Length; i++)
      {
        if (firstChar)
        {
          aux = hex[i];
          firstChar = false;
          continue;
        }
        if (hex[i] == '\n')
        {
          if (counter >= maxlinea && aux == '0')
          {
            sbLinea.Append(",");
          }
          else if (counter >= maxlinea && aux == 'F')
          {
            sbLinea.Append("!");
          }
          else if (counter > 20)
          {
            int multi20 = (counter / 20) * 20;
            int resto20 = (counter % 20);
            sbLinea.Append(CompressMap[multi20]);
            if (resto20 != 0)
            {
              sbLinea.Append(CompressMap[resto20] + aux);
            }
            else
            {
              sbLinea.Append(aux);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            sbLinea.Append(CompressMap[counter] + aux);
          }
          counter = 1;
          firstChar = true;
          if (sbLinea.ToString().Equals(previousLine))
          {
            sbCode.Append(":");
          }
          else
          {
            sbCode.Append(sbLinea.ToString());
          }
          previousLine = sbLinea.ToString();
          sbLinea.Length = 0;
          continue;
        }
        if (aux == hex[i])
        {
          counter++;
        }
        else
        {
          if (counter > 20)
          {
            int multi20 = (counter / 20) * 20;
            int resto20 = (counter % 20);
            sbLinea.Append(CompressMap[multi20]);
            if (resto20 != 0)
            {
              sbLinea.Append(CompressMap[resto20] + aux);
            }
            else
            {
              sbLinea.Append(aux);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            sbLinea.Append(CompressMap[counter] + aux);
          }
          counter = 1;
          aux = hex[i];
        }
      }
      return sbCode.ToString();
    }
    #endregion
  }

public static class ZplTools
  {
    public static string Normalize(string input)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return null;

      var sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
      {
        var byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(input.Substring(i, 1));
        var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray);
        sb.Append("_" + hexString.Replace("-", "_"));
      }

      return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static byte[] ConvertToMonochromeBitmap(byte[] imageData)
    {
      var converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
      var image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)converter.ConvertFrom(imageData);
      return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image.ConvertToMonochromeTiff(), typeof(byte[]));
    }
    public static byte[] ResizeImageData(byte[] imageData, int with, int height)
    {
      var converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
      using (var source = (System.Drawing.Image)converter.ConvertFrom(imageData))
      {
        using (var thumbnail = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(with, height))
        {
          using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail))
          {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, with, height);
          }

          return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(thumbnail, typeof(byte[]));
        }
      }
    }
    public static byte[] RotateImageData(byte[] imageData)
    {
      System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
      using (var image = (System.Drawing.Image)converter.ConvertFrom(imageData))
      {
        image.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
      }
    }
    public static string GetImageZplUploadString(byte[] imageData, string imageName)
    {
      return string.Format("^XA~DYE:{2},P,P,{0},,{1}^XZ", imageData.Length, ZplTools.GetASCIHexString(imageData), imageName);
    }
    public static string GetASCIHexString(byte[] data)
    {
      StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (byte b in data)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);

      return hex.ToString();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but adding a ^FWN command to the top of the ZPL solved the problem.

Comment: ^FW sets the default orientation for all fields accepting that parameter (only fields following the ^FW command) it looks like the printers assume different orientations for each, this would fix it